# Pull JSON Object from mongoDB and display in laravel Blade not working

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

Hi I am a novice when it comes to `PHP` And `MongoDB/Nosql`.

I am stuck with a problem. I need to fix this quickly so need the help of you guys.

When I go through `foreach loop` in `modal.blade.php`, I get the problem:

> Undefined index: 'question'

My Code Snippet is given below:

mysurveys.Blade.php

```
@extends('Templates.Datacollection.organization.index')

 <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-sm table-hover analytics-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($surveys as $survey=>$value)

                <tr class=" ? 'incompleted-survey' : 'completed-survey' }}">

                    <th scope="col">
                        <span class="response"></span>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Assign Permission">
                            <i class="fa fa-handshake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#{{ $value['_id'] }}" data-placement="top" title="Assign Permission">
                            <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                         @include('Modules.DataCOllection.organization.modal')                     
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger edit-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning copy-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Copy">
                            <i class="fa fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info delete-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm">
                            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>


                    </th>

                </tr>            
           <br> 
@endforeach



            </tbody>


        </table>
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

modal.Blade.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="{{ $value['_id'] }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">

          @php
          $var=$value['title'];
          @endphp

          {{ $var }}

          @php
          $survey=$value['question'];
          @endphp
          @foreach($survey as $item=>$value)
            @php
                $item=$value['question_type'];

            @endphp
          @endforeach


        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        @if($item==1)

        @foreach($survey as $item1=>$value)
          @php
            $item1=$value['question'];
          @endphp
          {{ $item1 }}
        @endforeach

        @elseif($item==2)

        @foreach($survey as $item2=>$value)
            @php
                $item2=$value['question'];
            @endphp
        @endforeach

        @elseif($item==3)

        @elseif($item==4)

        @elseif($item==5)

        @elseif($item==6)

        @elseif($item==7)

        @elseif($item==8)

        @else        

        @endif

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

AnalyticsController.Php

```
 public function view_survey(){

        $surveys=MongoSurvey::all();

        return view('Modules.DataCollection.organization.mysurveys',compact('surveys'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$surveys=MongoSurvey::all();` is probably returning a collection, not an array.

Changes your foreach loop to `@foreach($surveys as $survey)` and then access the model properties like `$survey->question`

Also, you don't need to set variables for each property you're echoing, simply use

```
{{ $survey->question }}
```

instead of:

```
@php
    $item1=$value['question'];
@endphp
{{ $item1 }}
```